# Is there a way to overwrite an existing array element?

Tags: excel, vba

I get a Subscript out of range error when I try to write it this way (this is just pseudo for the logic):

```
Dim var As Double
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim var_arr() As Variant
Dim z As Integer

z = 3
arr = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(150000, 4))
var_arr = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(10000, 1))

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 to 10000
    var = var_arr(i)
'arr(var, 3) is 0 and double before I try to write it
'and var is part of arr and there aren't any duplicates
    If IsInArray(var, arr) = True Then
        arr(var, 3) = z
    End If
Next i

PrintArray arr, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[A2]
```

Doing this in a worksheet is unfortunately not an option because it would took forever.

Here is the full code:

```
Sub WRITELAYERID()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Sheets("MINTA").Activate
Dim MINTA_array() As Variant
MINTA_array = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(46643, 4))

Sheets("ALAP").Activate
Dim ALAP_array() As Variant
ALAP_array = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(16482, 5))

Dim z As Long
For z = 1 To 14

    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim ID_array() As Variant

    Dim x As Long
    For x = 1 To 16481

        DoEvents

        If ALAP_array(x, 2) = z Then

            Dim a As Long
            Dim c As Long
            Dim d As Long

            a = ALAP_array(x, 1)
            c = ALAP_array(x, 3)
            d = ALAP_array(x, 4)

            Dim i As Long
            i = c

            Do While i <= d
                Dim ID_sample_string As String
                Dim ID_sample_number As Long
                Dim e As String
                If i < 10 Then
                    e = 0 & i
                Else
                    e = i
                End If

                ID_sample_string = a & e
                'ID_sample_number = CLng(ID_sample_string)
                'Excel 2010 function:
                ID_sample_number = CLng(Val(ID_sample_string)) 'Val is black not blue... maybe it is not working properly?
                col.Add ID_sample_number 'add to collection
                i = i + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next x

    ID_array = toArray(col) 'function: convert collection to an array

    Dim ID_array_Rows As Integer
    ID_array_Rows = UBound(ID_array, 1) - LBound(ID_array, 1) + 1

    Dim h As Integer
    For h = 1 To ID_array_Rows

        DoEvents

        Dim ID_sample As Double

        ID_sample = ID_array(h)

        If IsInArray(ID_sample, MINTA_array) = True Then 'function
            'MsgBox (VarType(ID_sample)) --> double
            'MsgBox (VarType(MINTA_array(1, 3))) --> double
            MINTA_array(ID_sample, 3) = MINTA_array(ID_sample, 3) + z 'HERE is the problem
        'End If



    Next h

Next z

PrintArray MINTA_array, ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("KESZ").[A2] 'function


End Sub
```

This is the IsInArray function:

```
Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function
    IsInArrayError:
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Link of my tables with examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAWNp.jpg
Table 1 is ALAP, Table 2 is MINTA

Comment: Apparently you created/found a function called `IsInArray` that checks if an element is in array. Apparently it can only work with 1D arrays, and `arr` is 2D.

Comment: @GSerg That part is functioning well. Returns false if it is false and true when it is true.

Comment: I am skeptical about this because of your `and var is part of arr and there aren't any duplicates`. `var` is an index for `arr` but you seem to treat it as an element, unless your `IsInArray` is a weird one that checks the array contains the index `i` rather than the element `i`. Anyway it would help if you said on which line you get the error from the beginning.

Comment: So what is the value of `ID_sample` and how does it compare to `LBound(MINTA_array, 1)` and `UBound(MINTA_array, 1)`?

Comment: `ID_sample` is withdrawn from the Collection. It was stored as `ID_sample_number`. `ID_array_Rows` shows the number of rows `ID_array` dyn array has that was made from the Collection.

Comment: I'm not asking where it comes from, I'm asking what exact numeric value it has when you receive the error. As it is clear from `IsInArray` you have posted, it looks for an element value, and you use its answer to decide that the array contains an index, which it does not. `IsInArray(ID_sample, MINTA_array)` returns `True` when at least one unknown element of `MINTA_array` equals `ID_sample`. It does not mean `MINTA_array` can be indexed as `MINTA_array(ID_sample)`.

Comment: 30325601 (double). When I check manually in `MINTA_array`, I can see it there too.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I'm saying. You can see *an element `30325601`* and then you are trying to access *row number `30325601`*. Does `MINTA_array` have at least `30325601` rows?

Comment: Ahhh!!!! NOW I see......... So how can I find the value and edit the corresponding layer number?

Comment: You create another function instead of `IsInArray` that explicitly iterates over two dimensions instead of relying on `For Each` and returns the first dimension when the element is found.

Comment: Ohh and I'm really grateful for your help!